# How to deploy Spring framework backend and Angular 2 frontend application in any online server?

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc, web-deployment

Please correct if the way I am doing is wrong.

In my web application I am not using jsp pages for developing user interface. Instead I am using html, css and Angular 2 and front-end project structure is separated from back-end.

Although I am able to develop a simple project using Angular CLI which is served by SpringMVC back-end. Front-end is using port 4200 and backend is running on port 8080. I have managed to take and serve request from Angular 2 to SpringMVC. In local mode these are working perfectly, now I want to make them host on a live server.

How to publish SpringMVC back-end and Angular 2 front-end separately but running on same domain? I am not using SpringBoot also front-end and back-end are in separate folders. I do not want to combine both in same project structure and generate a war file and deploy.

What is the best practice for developing SpringMVC back-end and Angular-2 back-end and deploying them in online server?

Comment: What you used for packaging the Angular 2 App? Which server you are using for deployment?

Comment: I have used webpack for packaging the Angular 2 App. Is it possible to deploy both back-end and front-end which are separate project in same server with same domain name? I do not have prior knowledge of deploying  web applications.

Answer (score 1):

What I've found works best is running nginx as a static file server and a forward proxy for the spring app.

usually I use the angular-cli proxy to make /api/ go to http://localhost:8080

that means that calls to http://localhost:3000/api/** get passed to http://localhost:8080/api/**. And since you are on the same domain we can simply call /api/**

Comment: That is already running fine for me. But can you tell me best procedure of deploying front-end and back-end in online server. As far from my knowledge after reading different blogs, they have suggested not to create a single war file combining both front-end and back-end. How to host front-end which is making request to SpringMVC back-end?

Comment: If you are using spring boot create a runnable jar file and launch it using systemd https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html now you have spring running on port 8080. now install nginx and create a nginx configuration that uses proxy_pass to send all requests for /api/ to spring. then ftp or rsync your angular files into the server and use nginx to serve them.