# Webserver for Angular and Spring application

Tags: spring, apache, angular, amazon-web-services, webserver

I'm building a small web application for a personal project. It will be an Angular web application which will talk to a Spring-Boot service layer which in turn will read/write stuff to MongoDb.

I hope to host all this on a single EC2 instance in AWS. My question is how to configure a web server (like Apache but doesn't have to be) to 'beautify' the URLs a bit. Example, without touching anything angular will run at something like `host:4200` and the service layer at `host:8080`. I will then have to map a proper domain to `host` in AWS, but the hiding of ports etc is where it gets murky for me.

I want to be able to hit my web app at `domain.com` (no ports etc) and I also want my service layer to ideally have a similar setup e.g. `domain.com/service` (no ports etc).

How do I configure a webservice to do this for me? Examples or pointers to specific examples would be ideal, but even a pointer to the right documentation will be helpful.

This thread is kind of similar to what I want but not too helpful: [How to deploy Spring framework backend and Angular 2 frontend application in any online server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006018/how-to-deploy-spring-framework-backend-and-angular-2-frontend-application-in-any)

Comment: you can the Microservices approach with Spring cloud Eureka service discovery API on both Angulr and Spring.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a setup with AWS CloudFront as reverse proxy and CDN cache. You can map the Domain Name and SSL Certificates(You can use AWS issued free SSL Certificates through AWS Certificate Manager) to CloudFront while the EC2 instance is plugged as an origin behind CloudFront as shown in the following diagram.

[image]

In the diagram I have optionally added, which is a common practice in designing applications in AWS.

- Hosting the Angular App in S3
- Using Autoscaling & Loadbalancing for EC2 instances.

Comment: Can you elaborate the steps on how to do this? Or at least provide relative links?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Apache or other web server as a reverse proxy. Start here -

https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/configure-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu/

You then will need to setup a custom domain name. The easiest option is to just use an ELB (now called Classic Load Balancer). More details are here -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html